# Pruebas unitarias en typescript enviando una dependencia con valor null

Tags: typescript, jest, unittest, dependencyinjection

Trato de hacer pruebas unitarias de una clase `typescript` que recibe mediante inyección de dependencias otra clase. Concretamente estoy teniendo problemas al testear el envío de un valor null en esta dependencia.

Esta sería la clase que quiero testear:

```
export class ClaseaTestear {
    private _diClass: IDiClass;

    public constructor(diClass: IDiClass) {
        if (!diClass)
            throw new Error("diClass can't be null");

        this._diClass = diClass;
    }
}
```

Esta sería la dependencia (`DiClass`):

```
export class DiClass implements IDiClass {
    public get Property1(): NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement> {
        return this.getProperty1();
    }

    private getProperty1() {
        return document.querySelectorAll<HTMLDivElement>('#id');
    }
}
```

Como indicaba anteriormente, la prueba en cuestión que intento crear es tratar de que `diClass` llegue con un valor `null` al constructor de `ClaseaTestear` y que se genere una excepción, pero no lo consigo.

En un principio traté de enviar directamente `null` a `ClaseaTestear` pero el propio `typscript` no me lo permite, por lo que la otra opción es usar mocks y aquí tampoco lo estoy consiguiendo. He seguido la documentación de `jest` sin mucho éxito y ahora mismo estoy en este punto:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { expect, jest, test } from '@jest/globals';
import { IDiClass, DiClass } from '../../app/DiClass';
import { ClaseaTestear } from '../../app/ClaseaTestear';

jest.mock('../../app/DiClass');

describe ('Test', () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    test('createInstance_DiClassIsNull_error', async () => {

        const DiClassMock = jest.mock('../../app/DiClass', () => {
            return {
                __esModule: true,
                default: jest.fn(() => null),
                Property1: jest.fn(() => null)
            }
        });

        const result = new ClaseaTestear(DiClassMock);

        expect(result).toThrow();
    
    });

};
```

En este punto no tengo muy claro si estoy planteándolo mal conceptualmente. ¿Es necesario realizar este tipo de tests en typescript? ¿O estoy planteando mal el test en si?

Espero que alguien pueda arrojar un poco de luz. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que en el constructor compruebas si la dependencia es `null` o `undefined`, pero no es una dependencia opcional (debería estar marcada como `public constructor(diClass?: IDiClass)` con la interrogación para ser opcional) así que el propio TS te "impide" no pasarle el tipo correcto ahí...

Por otro lado, lo que haces con tu mock no sirve para ese test porque realmente, aunque sea un mock, si cumple con el "contrato" de tu tipo y no es ni `null` ni `undefined` así que nunca va a tirar el error!!

Veamos una posible solución sencilla, pasarle un `null`!! Pero TS no te deja así que vamos a ser más listos que TS y decirle que lo que le estamos pasando no es `null`!

```
test('createInstance_DiClassIsNull_error', async () => {
  // usando as any forzamos a que TS se "trague" lo que metamos aquí, pues no comprobará el tipo
 // Puede ser cualquier cosa, puede incluso ser un IDiClass! Quien sabe, como es any ni se molesta en mirarlo
  const result = new ClaseaTestear(null as any);

  expect(result).toThrow();
});
```

Como ves, ya que vamos a pasar un `null` no hay necesidad ninguna de usar mocks!, simplemente tenemos que "*engañar*" a TS para que nos permita pasar el null y tu test ya debería de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: No he podido ejecutar el test porque no tengo ningún entorno con TS "limpio" a mano donde correrlo, pero no estoy seguro de que vaya a funcionar tal cual está escrito, el error saltará antes de ejecutar el expect lo que puede afectar a la ejecución del test en si mismo. Si eso ocurre siempre puedes invocar al constructor dentro del propio expect, imagino!

Comment: Desconocía lo que me comentas del "as any" y efectivamente, tienes razón. Ahora me pasa el test y sin necesidad de complicarme más de la cuenta con los mocks. Muchas gracias!